# Bootstrap collapse not working even though js loaded

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have the following data-toggle i want to collapse for the menu. I have provided the necessary bootstrap classes, but it's still not working either.

Html code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-compact">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a rel="nofollow" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" title="Toggle menu">
        <span class="menu-name">Menu</span>
        <span class="menu-bars">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="topMenu" data-submenu="horizontal">
          <li class=" active ">
            <a rel="nofollow" href="//ss-template-blog03.simplesite.com/434337774">FRONT PAGE</a>
          </li>
          <li class="  ">
            <a rel="nofollow" href="//ss-template-blog03.simplesite.com/434337775">BLOG</a>
          </li>
          <li class="  ">
            <a rel="nofollow" href="//ss-template-blog03.simplesite.com/434337777">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Bootstrap classes that i have loaded into my project

- bootstrap.collapse-2.3.2.js
- bootstrap.dropdown-2.3.2.js
- bootstrap.modal-2.3.2.js

I have my own CSS for the styling

This is how i load my js files
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 copy of Jquery.js files...
remove one of them
And include Bootstrap.js file after Jquery.js file.

Update:
Do not remove dot in ".nav-collapse" as suggested in another answer.

if this does not work.. try removing all other Bootstrap includes

I have Created Jsfidle:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/40014/]
```